# How to animate div height with web-animations-js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to animate div height using [web-animations-js](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js)?

In my example I try to change the height size from 150px to 300px. but I want to animate the height. I can't do that with css because the height is can be change (for example from 90px to 500px).

How to solve this by using web-animation-js?

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.some');
  
  var animation = elem.animate({
   height: '300px'
  }, {
   duration: 500
  });

  console.log('done');
```

```css
.some {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<div class="some"></div>
```

Comment: Why not possible in css ? Add a class with the new height, put an animation on this class, and apply the class to your element :)

Comment: Why dont you use the CSS ? Css Transform can help you.

Comment: because the height is determined by JavaScript. for example I decide when you click then the height is 500px.

Comment: How do you calculate the divs height ?

Comment: height is a random number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use velocity to do that. (using javascript)

Here is example:

```js
document.querySelector('.some').velocity({ height: 300 });
```

```css
.some {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.5/velocity.min.js" integrity="sha256-NtPQd/Jy7Ze2E72YS8WJDGMu6xFYomLYibE0hpyLTjs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="some"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let el = document.querySelector(".some");

el.style.transition = "all 2s ease-in-out 0s";

let randomHeight= ... ;

el.style.height = randomHeight+"px";
```

You get a height value "randomHeight" then this will be change the height of element.